# Dynamic "next" and "previous" step with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms

in a multistep form I'm using this code down below to go to the next or previous section of my form (only one step is visible, others are hide):

```
$(".next").click(function(){
   if (form.valid() === true){
        if ($('#one').is(":visible")){
            current_fs = $('#one');
            next_fs = $('#two');
        }else if($('#two').is(":visible")){
            current_fs = $('#two');
            next_fs = $('#three');
        }

   next_fs.show(); 
   current_fs.hide();
   }
 });

 $('#previous').click(function(){
    if($('#two').is(":visible")){
        current_fs = $('#two');
        next_fs = $('#one');
    }else if ($('#three').is(":visible")){
        current_fs = $('#three');
        next_fs = $('#two');
    }
    next_fs.show(); 
    current_fs.hide();
 });
```

This code working well if i have a 3-step form, but i want to modify my code using an array to go to next or previous step.

I've tried to use an array like this `var pages = ["#one","#two","#three"]` and use, for example `if ($(pages[0]).is(":visible"))` instead of `if ($('#one').is(":visible"))`

How can i modify this code to make it scalable (for example, if i want to add more pages)

thank you

Comment: Please post the html that you are using. That helps us to give perfect solution

Comment: html code is a form with some fieldset tag. each fieldset has an id witch is pages array.
with css all fieldset are set to display:none except that with id="one"

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if one worked for you... you'll find people less and less likely to help if you don't :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any arrays to store your steps. It's better to base on your HTML and CSS. Look at my solution: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/journeyman/9gm56g8t/)

So when you add new steps you don't need to modify your JavaScript at all. Just add new step to your HTML:

```
<div class="step active">
    1
</div>
<div class="step">
    2
</div>
<div class="step">
    3
</div>
<div class="step">
    4
</div>

<button id="prev" disabled="disabled">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Use CSS to hide all steps except active:

```
.step {
  display: none;
}

.step.active {
  display: block;
}
```

JavaScript in my case:

```
var index = $(".step.active").index(".step"),
    stepsCount = $(".step").length,
    prevBtn = $("#prev"),
    nextBtn = $("#next");

prevBtn.click(function() {
    nextBtn.prop("disabled", false);

    if (index > 0) {
        index--;
        $(".step").removeClass("active").eq(index).addClass("active");
    };

    if (index === 0) {
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    }
});

nextBtn.click(function() {
    prevBtn.prop("disabled", false);

    if (index < stepsCount - 1) {
        index++;
        $(".step").removeClass("active").eq(index).addClass("active");
    };

    if (index === stepsCount - 1) {
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, I'd add some error handling in case the next or previous indexes don't exist in your pages array.

```
$('#next').click(function(){
    if(form.valid() === true){
        var current_page = $(pages.join(",")).find(':visible');
        var current_index = pages.indexOf('#'+current_page.attr('id');
        current_page.hide();
        $(pages[current_index+1]).show();
    }
});
$('#previous').click(function(){
    var current_page = $(pages.join(",")).find(':visible');
    var current_index = pages.indexOf('#'+current_page.attr('id');
    current_page.hide();
    $(pages[current_index-1]).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated my code please check it. It is working. I have done some changes to jquery code. Please use it.

```js
   var form = $("#form");
         var pages = ["#one","#two","#three","#four","#five"];
         $(".next").click(function(){
            if (form.valid() === true){ 
             var temp = 0;
             var nextElementFound = false;
             pages.forEach(function(element) { 
            temp++;
                     if ($(element).is(":visible")){ 
                   current_fs =$(element);
             if(pages.length > temp){
             next_fs =$(pages[temp]);
             nextElementFound = true;
             }
            }
                 }); 
           if(nextElementFound){
                 next_fs.show(); 
                 current_fs.hide();
           }
            }
          });
         
          $('#previous').click(function(){
             var temp = 0;
          var previousElementFound = false;
          pages.forEach(function(element) { 
             if ($(element).is(":visible")){ 
                   current_fs =$(element);
             if(temp != 0){
             previousElementFound= true;
             next_fs =$(pages[temp-1]);
             }
            }
             temp++;
             }); 
          if(previousElementFound){
             next_fs.show(); 
             current_fs.hide();
          }
          });
```

```css
 #previous {
      border: 1px solid;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 10px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      }
      .next {
      border: 1px solid;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      min-width: 50px;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      }
      .customElement {
      background-color: gray;
      border: 1px solid;
      color: white;
      font-size: 35px;
      min-height: 30px;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      width: 148px;
      }
```

```html
<script
         src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
         integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
         crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
      <div>
         <form id="form">
            <div id ="one" class="customElement">
               one
            </div>
            <div id ="two" style="display:none" class="customElement">
               two
            </div>
            <div id ="three" style="display:none" class="customElement">
               three
            </div>
   <div id ="four" style="display:none" class="customElement">
               four
            </div>
   <div id ="five" style="display:none" class="customElement">
               five
            </div>
         </form>
         <div  id="previous" >
            Previous
         </div>
         <div class="next">
            Next
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I have updated my answer please check output in the code snippet.

Comment: i've modified my html using a "previous" class instead of an id and it worked. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of checking if ('#x') is visible I would keep a variable with the active page.
2. I would name the different form parts with a number convention such as '#form-part-1' instead of '#one'.

and last I would do

```
$(".next").click(function(){
   $("#form-part-"+activeIndex).hide();
   activeIndex++;
   $("#form-part-"+activeIndex).show(); 
});

$(".prev").click(function(){
   $("#form-part-"+activeIndex).hide();
   activeIndex--;
   $("#form-part-"+activeIndex).show(); 
});
```